# MySQL: Updatable view on different schema

Tags: mysql, view

I've read a few questions about MySQL workarounds for linked databases (like in Oracle) and found a simple solution if the tables are within the same MySQL-instance but in different schemas.

```
CREATE
DEFINER = `admin`@`localhost` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW schema1.my_view AS
SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM schema2.t1;
```

But I cannot manage to make this view updatable, so I can add, update or delete rows within my_view. Is it possible?

The user admin got dba-rights to the database so it should not be an issue of user rights.

Comment: What do yo mean by 'But I cannot manage to make this view editable'? what is that you are trying to edit?

Comment: I've changed the text above, hoping my question is clear now.